# Set selected value to 0 when passed selected value is not available in binded itemsource list

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I wanted to set selected value to 0 when passed selected value is not available in binded itemsource list.

**There is a class called Category as mentioned below:**

```
public class Category
{
   private long _CategoryID;
   public long CategoryID
   {
       get
       {
           return _CategoryID;
       }
       set
       {
           _CategoryID = value;
       }
   }
   private string _CategoryName;
   public string CategoryName
   {
       get
       {
           return _CategoryName;
       }
       set
       {
           _CategoryName = value;
       }
   }
}
```

**There is a window and a combobox inside that window. And combobox is defined as below:**

```
<ComboBox  Name="cbCagtegory" TabIndex="7" ItemsSource="{Binding CategoriesList}" SelectedValuePath="CategoryID" DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CategoryID}">
</ComboBox>
```

**In the back end of this window I have prepared a list of categories to bind with combobox and a property to set combobox selected value.**

```
List<Category> CategoriesList= new List<Category>();

private long _CategoryID;
public long CategoryID
{
   get
   {
      return _CategoryID;
   }
   set
   {
      _CategoryID = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("CategoryID");
   }
}
```

**Now let say, CategoriesList contains two records.**

```
a. CategoryID=0, CategoryName='Category1'
b. CategoryID=1, CategoryName='Category2'
c. CategoryID=2, CategoryName='Category3'
```

**Question**.

if I set CategoryId property value to 5. There will be nothing selected in the combobox.
At this time i wanted to set CategoryID=0 as selected value.
And I wanted to achieve this in XAML.

**What I have tried so far.**

```
1.Assigned FallBackValue=0 as below
 <ComboBox  Name="cbCagtegory" TabIndex="7" ItemsSource="{Binding CategoriesList}" SelectedValuePath="CategoryID" DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CategoryID,FallBackValue=0}">
</ComboBox>

2. Assigned TargetNullValue=0 as below
<ComboBox  Name="cbCagtegory" TabIndex="7" ItemsSource="{Binding CategoriesList}" SelectedValuePath="CategoryID" DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CategoryID,TargetNullValue=0}">
</ComboBox>
```

**Result**

None of them worked. nothing got selected in combobox.

Comment: CategoryID I am using is inside of a Model. And i wanted it to be generic so looking for a solution inside XAML.

Answer (score 0):

i would do this:

- change the combobox in xaml in this way

  ```
  <ComboBox  Name="cbCagtegory" TabIndex="7" ItemsSource="{Binding CategoriesList}"  DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName" SelectedItem="{Binding Selection}">
  </ComboBox>
  ```
- add this property

  ```
  private Category comboSelection;
  public Category ComboSelection
  {
      get
      {
          return ComboSelection;
      }
      set
      {
          ComboSelection= value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("ComboSelection");
      }
  }
  ```
- Change CategoryID like this

  ```
  private long _CategoryID;

  public long CategoryID
  {
      get
      {
          return _CategoryID;
      }
      set
      {
          _CategoryID = value;
          if((int)CategoryID > CategoriesList.Count -1)
          {ComboSelection= CategoriesList[0];}
          else
          {ComboSelection= CategoriesList[(int)CategoryID ];
           _CategoryID = 0;}
          RaisePropertyChanged("CategoryID");
      }
  }
  ```